# Date format suggestion (dd-mm-yy) during typing in html input field

Tags: jquery, html, date, input, placeholder

The question is more to do with the user interface and experience. So I have a date input field in my JSP page. I want a semi-transparent `dd-mm-yyyy` to be present while entering the date.

I currently have `dd-mm-yyyy` placeholder in place which comes up when the input field is in focus. But as soon as I type, the placeholder vanishes

```
<body>
<input type="tel" name="dobfield" id="dobfield" class="input_c" autocomplete="off" value='<s:property value="dobfield" />'>
<body>
```

as of now, when I click on the field, I get `dd-mm-yyyy` as a placeholder. But as soon as I start typing the placeholder vanishes.

This is the sequence of change that must happen while I type. Preferably, the `dd-mm-yyyy` must be semi-transparent or grey.

```
dd-mm-yyyy
1d-mm-yyyy
12-mm-yyyy
12-1m-yyyy
12-12-yyyy
12-12-1yyy
..
..
12-12-1996
```

Comment: Suggestion: You can have three input fields next to each other, each for dd, mm and yyyy separated by dash(-).
If you really want to achieve the one in question, some JS code will be needed, which keeps on changing input field value on keyup event.

Comment: I dont mind js css code.

Comment: Dear, Saad, This Is what I want my DOB to function like: (https://loan.icicibank.com/asset-portal/home-loan/check-eligibility)